# Function similar to nodeValue but returning HTML entities untouched

Tags: javascript, dom

I am working on a browser extension (a content script) where I want to process all the text on a webpage and replace some of the text without breaking the webpage.

I filter relevant nodes using createTreeWalker then I iterate over them:

```
let nodes = document.createTreeWalker(...);

while ((node = nodes.nextNode())) {
  let text = node.nodeValue;
  ...
}
```

The problem I have is that for a span like

```
<span class="a-text-bold">Product
                                    &rlm;
                                        :
                                    &lrm;
                                </span>
```

`node.nodeValue` returns a string like

```
"Product
                                    ‏
                                        :
                                    ‎
                                
"
```

When I modify the dom and replace the node with a new one, I break the formatting since I don't have the HTML entities `&rlm;` and `&lrm;`.
How can I retrieve the actual content of the span

```
"Product
                                    &rlm;
                                        :
                                    &lrm;
"
```

?

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button); [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/).

Answer (score 0):

Entities just encode characters (in this case, the characters [U+200F](https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/character.jsp?a=200F) and [U+200E](https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/character.jsp?a=200E)). Provided you don't replace them when replacing other things in the string, the marks will still be there once you finish the replacement. For instance, here are the code points of the characters in `&rlm;_&lrm;`:

```js
const text = document.getElementById("x").childNodes[0].nodeValue;
console.log(
    Array.from(text, (ch) => `0x${ch.codePointAt(0).toString(16).toUpperCase()}`).join(" ")
);
```

```html
<div id="x">&rlm;_&lrm;</div>
```

As you can see, the marks are there.

The `&rlm;`/`&lrm;` in your example doesn't seem to do anything, but using some text from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-to-left_mark#Example_of_use_in_HTML), here's an example of updating `nodeValue` and how it doesn't strip away the `&rlm;` or `&lrm;`:

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll(".a-text-bold");
let counter = 0;
setInterval(() => {
    for (const element of elements) {
        const textNode = element.childNodes[0];
        const from = counter % 2 === 0 ? "enjoyed" : "loved";
        const to   = counter % 2 === 0 ? "loved" : "enjoyed";
        textNode.nodeValue = textNode.nodeValue.replace(from, to);
    }
    ++counter;
}, 1000);
```

```html
<p class="a-text-bold">I enjoyed staying -- באמת!&rlm; -- at his house.</p>
<p>For comparison, here's that text <strong>without</strong> the &amp;rlm; =></p>
<p class="a-text-bold">I enjoyed staying -- באמת! -- at his house.</p>
<p>Notice how the ! appears before (rather than after) the hebrew text when the &amp;rlm; is present, and that it still does after the replacement has been done.</p>
```